# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed when calling my .save() function on the serializer

Tags: python, django, database, constraints

So I've created a singleton class to store a file on my server that gets replaced every time a new file is added, but I'm getting the following error whenever I try to post in a new file to my upload endpoint and I've narrowed it down to when I call file_serializer.save()

> sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: api_app_onixfile.id

Models.py

```
class SingletonModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = 1
        super(SingletonModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        obj, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)
        return obj

class OnixFile(SingletonModel):
    onix_file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, validators=[validate_xml])
    def __str__(self):
        return self.onix_file.name
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import XMLFileSerializer
from .models import OnixFile
import onixcheck
from .utils import OnixParser
from django.http import JsonResponse


class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):


        file_serializer = XMLFileSerializer(data=request.data)

        if(file_serializer.is_valid()):

            onix_file = request.data['onix_file']
            onix_errors = onixcheck.validate(onix_file)
            if len(onix_errors) > 0:
                file_serializer.save()
                print("Onix Errors")
                return Response(onix_errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            else:
                file_serializer.save()
                print(OnixFile.load())
                return Response(OnixFile.load().__str__(), status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import OnixFile

class XMLFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OnixFile
        fields = "__all__"
```

I assumed my SingletonModel save function would handle the fact that I can't have a unique PK by overwriting the current function with new info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are posting and passing data into the serializer, it's attempting to create a new `OnixFile`. This means when `save()` is called by the serializer, it's trying to set the `id` of this new `OnixFile` instance to `1`, which is likely taken by your existing singleton instance.

If you'd rather update your singleton with new data, I'd suggest passing an `instance` into the serializer instead. That way, the serializer will attempt to update that instance and you can save the update instead of trying to make a new one:

```py
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Feel free to use `first()` or do some other check here in case you
        # have a case where the singleton might not exist.
        singleton_instance = OnixFile.objects.get(id=1)
        file_serializer = XMLFileSerializer(instance=singleton_instance, data=request.data)

        if(file_serializer.is_valid()):
            ...
```